# ubuntu14.04 python3.4 unable to pip3 matplotlib

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, matplotlib

**Have searched other similar questions, with no success. Do I just have to go back to Python 2.7?**

ubuntu 14.04 on Intel 32b desktop. Was using Python2.7 everything OK.  Now installed Idle for Python3.4 using Ubuntu Software Center.  It works but

```
import matplotlib
```

results in

```
matplotlib not found
```

and then

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

results in a huge amount of benign looking output but ends with errors.  Here is the last of the pip log file:

```
running install_lib

copying pylab.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pylab.py'

---------------------------------------- Cleaning up...   
>Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_jim... Command /usr/bin/python3 -c
"import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_jim/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-77rf26vy-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_jim/matplotlib Exception information: Traceback
(most recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in
run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)   File
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 707, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)   File
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 715, in
call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import
setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_jim/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-77rf26vy-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_jim/matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pylab.py'
```

indicates the script is trying to write in the directory `/usr/local`.

Run the command as a super user:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Comment: yes!  that made ALL the errors go away and now matplotlib is installed.